# Get category of a job details in relational tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the category of a job record, but is not showing nothing.

My table jobs is:

```
- id;
- title
- category_id;
..
```

Where I have than a list of categories on a table called "categories"

```
categories:
- id;
- title;
```

In my Category model I insert :

```
public function jobs(){
        return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
    }
```

But when I call in my loop the function it appears blank the category name.

ex:

```
<thead>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Titulo</th>
                <th>Category</th>


                <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($jobs as $job)
                    <tr>
                        <th>{{$job->id}}</th>
                        <td>{{$job->title}}</td>
                        <td>{{$job->jobs}}</td>

                        <td>{{ date('M j, Y h:ia', strtotime($job->created_at))}}</td>

                    </tr>

                @endforeach
```

Comment: what did you do in your Job model?

Comment: there is nothing in the job model

Comment: You should have a function, with the proper relation that you want. Most likely for you is hasOne, or belongsTo.

Answer (score 0):

How about `category` function in your `Job` model?

```
public function category(){
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class);
}
```

Then in your blade

```
<td>{{ $job->category->title }}</td>
```

Comment: didnt work, when i did this it was expecting that in the categories table had a job_id, so i replace hasOne by belongsTo and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one to many relationship from category to jobs then write this in your jobs model

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
}
```

Then you can get category from blade

```
<td>{{ $job->category->title }}</td>
```

Note that : **belongsTo** is reverse relationship of **one to many**. Your relationship is **one to many** from category to jobs and **Many to one** from jobs to category. In laravel **many to one** relationship is defined as **belongsTo**